# How to change the extent and position of an existing image in bokeh?

Tags: bokeh

I am displaying 2d data as images of varying shapes in a bokeh server, and therefore need to dynamically update not only the image's data source, but also its `dw`, `dh`, `x`, and `y` properties. In the dummy example below, these changes are made in a callback function which is connected to a `Button` widget.

I've figured out that I need to access the `glyph` attribute of the image's `GlyphRenderer` object, and I can do so through its `update()` method (see code). But the changes don't take effect until I click the toolbar's Reset button. I've noticed that the changes also mysteriously take effect the second time I activate the `callback()` function. What is the proper way to make these changes?

```
import bokeh.plotting
import bokeh.models
import bokeh.layouts
import numpy as np

# set up the interface
fig1 = bokeh.plotting.figure(x_range=(0, 10), y_range=(0, 10))
im1 = fig1.image([], dw=5, dh=5)
button = bokeh.models.Button(label='scramble')

# add everything to the document
bokeh.plotting.curdoc().add_root(bokeh.layouts.column(button, fig1))

# define a callback and connect it
def callback():
    # this always works:
    im1.data_source.data = {'image': [np.random.random((100,100))]}

    # these changes only take effect after pressing the "Reset" 
    # button, or after triggering this callback function twice:
    im1.glyph.update(x=1, y=1, dw=9, dh=9)
button.on_click(callback)
```

Comment: all of this is run with `bokeh serve`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't immediately see why you code isn't work. I can suggest explicitly using a ColumnDataSource and linking all of the Image glyph properties to columns in that source. Then you should be able to update the source.data in a single line and have all of the updates apply.

Here's some incomplete sample code to suggest how to do that:

```
from bokeh.models import Image, ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.plotting import figure

# the plotting code
plot = figure()
source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(image=[], x=[], y=[], dw=[], dh=[]))
image = Image(data='image', x='x', y='y', dw='dw', dh=dh)
plot.add_glyph(source, glyph=image)

# the callback
def callback():
    source.data = {'image': [np.random.random((100,100))], 'x':[1], 'y':[1], 'dw':[9], 'dh':[9]}

button.on_click(callback)
```